# How i can play [UInt8] audio stream?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, core-audio

I am connected to the server via TCP / IP and receives [UInt8]. I know that it is the audio. How to play the stream on the iPhone?

```
@IBAction func connectAndListen(sender: AnyObject) {
    var client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "80.233.248.96", port: 6969)
    var (success,errmsg)=client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success{
        while (success){
            var (success,errmsg)=client.send(str:"GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" )
            if success{
                var data = client.read(1024*10)
                if let d = data{

                    var endMarker = NSMutableData(bytes: d, length: d.count)
                    println(endMarker)
                    self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: endMarker, error: nil)

                    self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                    self.audioPlayer?.play()

                }
            }else{
                println(errmsg)
                break
            }
        }
    }else{
        println(errmsg)
    }
}
```

my Crash:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this self.audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay() [Print screen my crash](https://yadi.sk/i/LTF_blQyiJLGu)

Comment: You need to provide details about the crash. Which line and what is the complete error message?

Comment: @rmaddy my crash in  player.prepareToPlay() and in console log : ( fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value )

Comment: Why did you delete all your code from the question? You should put the code back and add details about the crash. Then your question may get reopened.

Comment: @rmaddy  come back my code and link printscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an `NSData` object from the bytes in your stream.
2. Create an `AVAudioPlayer` using the `initWithData:error:` method.
3. Play the audio using the `AVAudioPlayer` play method.

I cannot tell you exactly how to create the `NSData` object, because I don't know how you get your byte stream, but the `NSData` class is well documented in the Apple documentation.

Comment: @michael-l add more details in my question.